# Angular transclude directive inside another transclude directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, transclusion

I have an angular directive inside of another directive. Both use `transclude: true`.

I would expect if I had the following code (taken from the plunker) that I would see the same thing 3 times.

https://plnkr.co/edit/iIyU65WdMr4jDQyKZpt1?p=preview

JS:

```
angular.module('app', [])

.directive('myButton', myButton)

.directive('directiveWithDirective', directiveWithDirective)

.directive('directiveWithDiv', directiveWithDiv);

function myButton(){
  return {
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            template: '<button ng-transclude> </button>'
        };
}

function directiveWithDirective(){
  return {
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            template: '<my-button ng-transclude> </my-button>'
        };
}

function directiveWithDiv(){
  return {
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            template: '<div ng-transclude> </div>'
        };
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <my-button>
    A Button
  </my-button>
  <br>
  <directive-with-directive>
    A Button
  </directive-with-directive>
  <br>
  <directive-with-div>
    <div>
      <my-button>
        A Button
      </my-button>
    </div>
  </directive-with->
</div>
```

`my-button` and `directive-with-div` behave as I would expect. They include their content in the template.

However, `directive-with-directive` does not. I would expect the text "a button" to be included inside of `my-button` then, `my-button` be expanded into a button. Instead I see a blank directive:

```
<my-button ng-transclude=""> </my-button>.
```

I expect

```
<my-button ng-transclude=""><button>A Button</button> </my-button>
```

My questions are:

What am I misunderstanding about this? Is it related to the order in which directives are expanded by angular? Can I change this?

How can I achieve having a directive with transclusion within another transcluded directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can solve your problem with this :

```
function directiveWithDirective(){
  return {
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            template: '<my-button><ng-transclude /> </my-button>'
        };
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! This is exactly what I was looking for. Must have missed it. Updated plunker with working solution: https://plnkr.co/edit/E8oE2qaTfgSCtCGMYwMO?p=preview

Comment: @etiennecrb Found more info here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude